# Select latest item in list except when property has a certain value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need to get the latest status for each product in a list. Except if the status is "Success" it should be returned instead of the latest status. I have the following query to get the latest item but not sure how to conditionally select items that have the Success status. E.g. in the table below ProductId 1 should return the SUCCESS row but not the CANCEL row which is the latest one. Any ideas how to solve this in a single linq query?

```
var query = list
    .GroupBy(g => g.ProductId)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(s => s.Created)
                                          .FirstOrDefault())
    .Select(s => new ProductDto
    {
         ProductId = s.ProductId,
         Created = s.Created,
         Status = s.Status
    });

ProductId         Created                         Status
1                 2021-08-19 00:34:30             PREPARING
1                 2021-08-19 00:35:30             VALIDATE
1                 2021-08-19 00:36:30             SUCCESS
1                 2021-08-19 00:37:30             CANCELLED
2                 2021-08-19 00:36:30             PREPARING
2                 2021-08-19 00:38:30             VALIDATE
```

Comment: Can you add data example with expected result?

Comment: @vernou see the data table above

Comment: `g.OrderBy(s => s.Status == "SUCCESS" ? 0 : 1).ThenByDescending(s => s.Created)`

Comment: @Charlieface thanks for your answer. Could you explain what's happning if status is SUCCESS and the outcome is g.OrderBy(0) does this ignore ordering in general or does it sort desc vs asc(1) ?

Comment: It will first sort by `0` or `1`, and then by `Created`, so all `SUCCESS` rows will always come first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort first by whether it's a `SUCCESS` row:

```cs
.Select(g => g.OrderBy(s => s.Status == "SUCCESS" ? 0 : 1)
              .ThenByDescending(s => s.Created)
              .FirstOrDefault())
```

This causes all `SUCCESS` rows to come first, sorted by date, then the other rows, also sorted by date.

The intermediate sort (before `FirstOrDefault`) is effectively:

```
ProductId         Created                         Status
1                 2021-08-19 00:36:30             SUCCESS
1                 2021-08-19 00:37:30             CANCELLED
1                 2021-08-19 00:35:30             VALIDATE
1                 2021-08-19 00:34:30             PREPARING
2                 2021-08-19 00:38:30             VALIDATE
2                 2021-08-19 00:36:30             PREPARING
```